# PhpStorm Code Style - Automatically remove spaces from around assignment operator, only in default argument values in functions

Tags: php, phpstorm, whitespace

In trying to respect the coding style used at work, I've configured PhpStorm to respect all the requirements, with the exception of one:

- no spaces before and after the assignment operator (`=`) when it's used for default argument values in functions. So for example it should look like this

  ```
  public function sampleMethod($a, $b=null)
  ```

Ignoring the validity of this rule, I would like to know how I could set this up in PhpStorm's Code Style section (or somewhere else?) so the IDE takes it into account and applies it each time I do a *Reformat Code* for example. 
I've not been able to find a setting for this, unless I apply it to other contexts where the assignment operator is used, which is something I don't want.

Comment: why you don't use a https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer ? and maybe these too: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Code+Sniffer+in+PhpStorm and https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Mess+Detector+in+PhpStorm. And what you are searching is maybe the `Code Style->PHP->Spaces->Around Operators->Assignment operators`, but this will do for all assignment oeprators (therefore is better a cs-fixer )

Comment: Thanks for the options. 
PHP-CS-Fixer or maybe even Mess Detector seem to allow me to do what I need, in an easier fashion than creating an entire custom coding standard just for this tiny little rule.

Comment: There is no separate setting just for that place (default value in function declaration). Consider submitting Feature Request ticket to the PhpStorm's Issue Tracker if you need it (with good description) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it in phpstorm by going to

> Settings > Editor > Code Style > PHP

and there go to tab

> Spaces

and unchek the

> Assingment opratores

if you have problem with this let me know

Comment: This affects assignment operators in all contexts, not just in the one I want, namely within function declarations, for default values.

I still want proper spacing in all other cases.